# Debugging mocha-cakes-2 with Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a node.js project tested with mocha.js. I use [mocha-cakes-2](https://github.com/iensu/mocha-cakes-2) to write my test in cucumber style.

This is my package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"chai-spies": "^1.0.0",
"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"mocha-cakes-2": "^3.3.0",
"should": "^13.2.3",
"should-sinon": "0.0.6",
"sinon": "^6.3.4"},"scripts": {"test": "mocha ./scenarios/**/*.test.js --ui mocha-cakes-2"}
```

This is my launch.json in VS Code

```
{
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Mocha All",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
          "args": [
              "--timeout",
              "999999",
              "--colors",
              "'${workspaceFolder}/tests/scenarios/**/*.test.js'"
          ],
          "console": "integratedTerminal",
          "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
      }
```

When I run the tests everything works perfectly. But when I debug the tests with VS Code I get the following error. ReferenceError: feature is not defined

How can I configure VS Code debug options to set mocha-cakes-2 as the UI for mocha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should work by passing the `ui` params

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Mocha All",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "args": [
    "--ui", // add it here
    "mocha-cakes-2", // add it here
    "--timeout",
    "999999",
    "--colors",
    "'${workspaceFolder}/tests/scenarios/**/*.test.js'"
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```